# Modify jQuery plugin generated HTML

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using a jQuery plugin (that I did not write) in angular.  I wrapped the plugin in a directive and I call `$(element).jQueryFunction()` on it and the plugin generates a bunch of HTML.  The HTML the plugin generates isn't quite how I want it.  What is the angular best practice in modifying the generated HTML?  Is there a better way than just accessing the DOM with a jQuery selector after the plugin created it's HTML?

What I have so far:

```
//controller
angular.module('we', [])
.directive('jQueryPlugIn', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) { 
            $(element).jQueryFunction({option1: "value1"});
            $(".next").addClass("invisible");  //<------ is there a better way than this?
        }
});


//view
<body>
    <div j-query-plug-in></div>
</body>
```

Comment: did you happen to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a jQuery plugin, edit the plugin using jQuery, don't you think? But if you want to do it with angularjs [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) can help you.
s

Comment: I am hesitant to modify the plugin because it's 3rd party plugin brought in using bower.  If I modify the plugin, the next time someone does 'bower install' my changes could be gone.  I could customize the plugin, but then those if then if the next version of the plugin comes around I am stuck with my customized version.

Also, I'm not sure how ng-show helps me.  Maybe I wasn't clear, but the <div j-query-plug-in></div> element is replace by a bunch of html that the plugin generates.  Where would I put the ng-show?